# how to find order and name from text using regular expression

Tags: regex

I wanted to search order and name from from following text

payment for order: 792519
Taylor Mitsuuchi, Thank you for your order. We have received your items and issued a payment for your items. Here is a summary of the payment: Order Number: 792519 Payment Method: Check Payable To: Taylor Mitsuuchi Address: 330

Comment: What langauge are you using?

Comment: i am using c#The solution recommended by ruben ignore Order: xxxxxx string

Answer (score 0):

Order:

`/Order Number: (\d+)/`

or

`/order: (\d+) /`

Name:

`/Check Payable To: (.+) Address/`

or

`/order: \d+ (.+), Thank you/`

Comment: it ignores string order:XXXXX-   is there be way to extract all existence of string like order [ optional - number] : XXXXX  firstname last name

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but why?

Comment: well i am trying to do it in one go in c#

Comment: I mean why you want double extraction?

Comment: well program re write paragraph with some new standards like the Order string will be replace by ORDER_NUMBER:XXXXXX  and same same goes with names .. FIRSTNAME:dfdjfsdfjs LASTNAME:dsflsdfjsdlkf

Comment: Look. If you doing template work, you need no "find", but "replace". In this case, your template string should be prepared like: `payment for order: 1_ 2_, Thank you for your order. We have received your items and issued a payment for your items. Here is a summary of the payment: Order Number: 1_ Payment Method: 3_ Payable To: 2_ Address: 4_ ` etc. Finally, you should replace: `/1_/`, by the order number, `/2_/` by the name etc.